# How can I link a SQL image column to an external database?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I need a bit of a help with the following.

**Note**: in the following scenario, I do not have access to the application's source code, therefore I can only make changes at the database level.

Our database uses `dbo.[BLOB]` to store all kinds of files and documents. The table uses an `IMAGE` (yeah, obsolete) data type. Since this particular table is growing quite fast, I was thinking to implement some archiving feature.

My idea is to move all files older than X months to a second database, and then somehow link from the `dbo.[BLOB]` table to the external/archiving database.

Is this even possible? The goal is to reduce the database size, in order to improve backup and query performance.

Any ideas and hints much appreciated.

Thanks.
Fabian

Comment: Which **version** (2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016) of SQL Server is this for?

Comment: 2008 R2 Standard

Comment: [FILESTREAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx) storage is available since 2005. You can store such data outside the database and still backup the datase as a whole. If you don't want to backup the files, you can perform a partial backup

Comment: Even if you do want to store the data remotely (ie not on a file share), eg in a robotic disk array, you can do so using [Remote BLOB storage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638709(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos FILESTREAM is not available in 2005, [was added in 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645577(v=sql.100).aspx).

Comment: @RemusRusanu is "added on some past unsupported version over a decade ago" better? It's available in 2008 R2 to address this exact scenario. RBS was added later to handle even more diverse storage scenarios, especially for document management systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 features to help you with backup speed and database size in this case:

[Filestream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx) will allow you to store BLOBS as files on the file system instead of in database file. It complicates backup scenario, you have to backup both database and files but you get smaller database file along with faster access time to documents. It is much faster to read file from filesystem than from blob column. Additionally filestream allows for files bigger than 2GB.

[Partitioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx) will split table into smaller chunks on physical level. This way you do not need to access application code to change where particular rows are stored physically and decide which data needs to be accessed fast and put it on SSD drive and which can land on slower archive. This way you can have more frequent backups on current partition, while less frequent on archive.

Prior to SQL Server 2016 SP1 - this feature was available in Enterprise version only. For SQL Server 2016 SP1 this is available in all editions.

In your case most likely you should go with filestream first.

Comment: Thanks. From what I read, partitioning is only available on enterprise versions. As for the filestream solution, I need to read further if there are any consequences attached, such as re-writing queries etc...

Comment: Partitioning has nothing to do with this. The appropriate feature is FILESTREAM storage

Answer (score 0):

W/o modifying the application you can do, basically, nothing. You may try to see if changing the column type will be tolerated by the application (very unlikely, 99.99% it will break the app) and try to use FILESTREAM, but even if you succeed it does not give much benefits (backup size will be the same, for example).

A second thing you can try is to replace the table with a view, using [`INSTEAD OF` triggers for updates](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288(v=sql.105).aspx). It is still very likely to break the application (lets say 99.98%). The goal would be to have a [distributed partitioned](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188299(v=sql.105).aspx) view (or cross DB partitioned view) which presents to the application an unified view of the 'cold' and 'hot' data. Is complex, [error prone](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2007/06/20/distributed-partitioned-views-federated-databases-lessons-learned/), but it *will* reduce the size of the backups (as long as data is moved from hot to cold and cold data is immutable, requiring few backups).

> The goal is to reduce the database size, in order to improve backup and query performance.

To reduce the backup size, as I explained above, you can do, basically, nothing. But performance you need to [**investigate it**](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) and address it appropriately, based on your findings. Saying the the database is slow 'because of BLOBs' is hand-waving.

Comment: FILESTREAM answers all these concerns without modifying the application. You can exclude FILESTREAM data from backups by using a partial backup. Even if you do need remote storage and a file share won't do (why?), the feature is available through [Remote Blob Storage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638709(v=sql.105).aspx). Remote can easily mean a storage appliance like a robotic disk array.

Comment: If the application is using `IMAGE` then is very unlikely to support a change to `VARBINARY(MAX)`, since they are different fundamental types. Whatever bindings are used at data acceess, will break, and the API to manipulate IMAGE types is different (think `TEXTPTR`, `READTEXT` et all). If the application would had already been using `VARBINARY(MAX)` then adding `FILESTREAM` would be more viable. Anyhow, is just speculation and OP needs to answer if the app works with VARBINARY(MAX) and FILESTREAM.

Comment: As for partial backups, they do not require FILESTREAM. Simply use `TEXTIMAGE_ON` on the *existing* table structure and you can then do partial backups that skip the IMAGE blobs. Bu the point is that then one still needs to backup *new* BLOBs, so only moving BLOBs to a new FG does not solve the problem. Partitioning would be needed to move  **rows** to cold storage and then declare the FG read-only. And this is entirely orthogonal to use of FS, FS add nothing to the equation. Not to mention how error-prone is to do a correct backup scheme with partials...

Comment: `image` is a synonym for `varbinary(max)` and I didn't say you need FILESTREAM for partial backups, I said that you can use partial backups if you don't want to backup FILESTREAM files. Anyway, moving to a different database isn't better that storing to a separate disk or share. Especially when such storage is managed by the DB itself

Comment: "`image` is a synonym for `varbinary(max)`" please do not disseminate such bad misinformation.

Comment: I haven't used these keywords for over a decade, so I think I can be excused. Saying that FILESTREAM doesn't offer the very benefits it was created to offer though, or proposing triggers, isn't very robust.  It would be more robust to change the field types to `varbinary(max)`. The modifications required by triggers would be more extensive than changing the ADO.NET code to use `GetSqlBytes` instead of `GetSqlBinary`

Comment: Thanks for all the input. As I said, we do not have any access to the source code of the application. Personally, I would not want to use FILESTREAM in this particular case, because I am 100% sure it will break the application, since its not really robust. Partitioning seems to be the better choice but requires an upgrade of the SQL server.

Comment: "not really robust" refers to the application